# Vuetify with VueDraggable : v-img is not loaded as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuedraggable

I am trying to use vueDraggable with vuetify, to create a photo gallery which allowed to rearrange the order.

Without Draggable, the v-img is loading the image correctly.
While after I added the draggable, the images is not going to be loaded.
To test the images path is correct, I added a  below the  and the  are loaded properly.

https://codepen.io/brian661/pen/zVygap/

```
<template xmlns:v-slot="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex xs12>
      <v-card>
        <v-container grid-list-sm fluid>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <draggable
                class="draggableArea"
                :list="photos"
                :group="{ name: 'photo', pull: 'clone', put: false }"
                :sort= false
            >
            <v-flex
                v-for="photo in photos"
                :key=photo.name
                xs3
                d-flex
            >
              {{photo.name}}
              <v-card flat tile class="d-flex">
                // this is not able to be loaded
                <v-img
                    :contain="true"
                    :src=photo.img
                    :lazy-src=photo.img
                    class="grey lighten-2"
                >
                  // this is loaded without problem
                  <img :src=photo.img class="Photo"/>
                  <template v-slot:placeholder>
                    <v-layout
                        fill-height
                        align-center
                        justify-center
                        ma-0
                    >
                      <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="grey lighten-5"></v-progress-circular>
                    </v-layout>
                  </template>
                </v-img>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
            </draggable>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

  export default {
    name: "AvailablePhoto",
    components: {
      draggable,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        photos : [ {name: "photo1", img: "https://somewhere/1.png"},
          {name: "photo2", img: "https://somewhere/2.png"},
          {name: "photo3", img: "https://somewhere/3.png"},
          {name: "photo3", img: "https://somewhere/4.png"}]
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .draggableArea {
    display: flex;
  }
  .Photo {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in codepen?

Comment: First time to use codepen, I think this link work?
https://codepen.io/brian661/pen/zVygap/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<v-img :src="require('photo.img')"></v-img>
```

instead of

```
<v-img :src="photo.img"></v-img>
```

> Vue loader converts relative paths into require functions automatically for you. Unfortunately, this is not the case when it comes to custom components. You can circumvent this issue by using require. If you're using Vuetify as a Vue-CLI 3 plugin, you can edit your project's vue.config.js file by modifying the options for vue-loader.

```
// Incorrect
<v-img src="../path/to/img" />

// Correct
<v-img :src="require('../path/to/img')" />
```

Source: [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#relative-images-are-not-working-in-v-card-v-img-and-other-custom-vuetify-components)

Hope it helps.